# what is wrong in this java file path?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

im getting the "Can't read input file!" in next chunk of code

```
try {
            slate = ImageIO.read(new File("flor.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

why is that happening if the image is in the same place with the .java file ?

Comment: Maybe the input file is not found? It should be at the root folder of project

Comment: Path is relative to your current directory: the directory from which you run the program, not the directory of the class file necessarily.

Comment: ... or the directory of the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below code to check if your image is listed current directory

```
File file = new File(".");
for(String fileNames : file.list()) System.out.println(fileNames);
```

Comment: indeed i was missing a "./src/PackageName/flor.jpg" thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for example:
if you project:  test in eclipse

```
test
----src/*.java
----flor.jpg
```